# Replace parts of a variable using numeric indices in dplyr. Do I need to create an index column and use ifelse?

Tags: r, dplyr

At one stage in longer chain of `dplyr` functions, I need to replace parts of a variable using numeric indices to specify which elements to replace.

My data looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:2, each = 3),
                  a = 1:6,
                  b = rep(c(10, 20), each = 3))
df1   
#   grp a  b
# 1   1 1 10
# 2   1 2 10
# 3   1 3 10
# 4   2 4 20
# 5   2 5 20
# 6   2 6 20
```

Assume that we, within each group, wish to replace elements in variable `a` with the corresponding elements in `b`, at one or more positions. In this simple example I use a single index (`id`), but this could be a vector of indices. First, here's how I would do it with `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
id <- 2    
ddply(.data = df1, .variables = .(grp), function(x){
  x$a[id] <- x$b[id]
  x
})

#   grp  a  b
# 1   1  1 10
# 2   1 10 10
# 3   1  3 10
# 4   2  4 20
# 5   2 20 20
# 6   2  6 20
```

In `dplyr` I could think of some different ways to perform the replacement. (1) Use `do` with an anonymous function, similar to the one used in `ddply`. (2) Use `mutate`: concatenate a vector where the replacement is 'inserted' using numeric indexing. This is probably only fruitful for a single index. (3) Use `mutate`: create an index vector and use conditional replacement with `ifelse` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078891/how-to-update-values-with-dplyr/23083183#23083183), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438476/dplyr-idiom-for-summarize-a-filtered-group-by-and-also-replace-any-nas-due-to), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/dplyr-how-to-combine-mutate-with-conditional-values/22337459#22337459), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619273/absolute-and-percent-change-by-rows/23619558#23619558)).

```
detach("package:plyr", unload = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

# (1)
fun_do <- function(df){
  l <- df %.%
    group_by(grp) %.%
    do(function(dat){
      dat$a[id] <- dat$b[id]
      dat
    })
  do.call(rbind, l)
}

# (2)
fun_mut <- function(df){
  df %.%
  group_by(grp) %.%
  mutate(
    a = c(a[1:(id - 1)], b[id], a[(id + 1):length(a)])
    )
}

# (3)
fun_mut_ifelse <- function(df){
  df %.%
    group_by(grp) %.%
    mutate(
      idx = 1:n(),
      a = ifelse(idx %in% id, b, a)) %.%
    select(-idx)
}

fun_do(df1)
fun_mut(df1)
fun_mut_ifelse(df1)
```

In a benchmark with a slightly larger data set, the 'jigsaw puzzle insertion' is fastest, but again, this method is probably only suited for single replacements. And it doesn't look very clean...

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:200, each = 3),
                  a = rnorm(600),
                  b = rnorm(600))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun_do(df2),
               fun_mut(df2),
               fun_mut_ifelse(df2),
               times = 10)

# Unit: microseconds
#                expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#         fun_do(df2) 48443.075 49912.682 51356.631 53369.644 55108.769    10
#        fun_mut(df2)   891.420   933.996  1019.906  1066.663  1155.235    10
# fun_mut_ifelse(df2)  2503.579  2667.798  2869.270  3027.407  3138.787    10
```

Just to check the influence of the `do.call(rbind` part in the `do` function, try without it:

```
fun_do2 <- function(df){
  df %.%
    group_by(grp) %.%
    do(function(dat){
      dat$a[2] <- dat$b[2]
      dat
    })
}
fun_do2(df1)
```

Then a new benchmark on a larger data set:

```
df3 <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:2000, each = 3),
                  a = rnorm(6000),
                  b = rnorm(6000))

microbenchmark(fun_do(df3),
               fun_do2(df3),
               fun_mut(df3),
               fun_mut_ifelse(df3),
               times = 10)
```

Again, a simple 'insertion' is fastest, while the `do` function is losing ground. In the help text `do` is described as "a general purpose complement" to the other `dplyr` functions. To me it seemed to be a natural choice for an anonymous function. However, I was surprised that `do` was so much slower, also when the non-`dplyr` `rbind`ing part was skipped. Currently, the `do` documentation is rather scarce, so I wonder if I am abusing the function, and that there may be more appropriate (undocumented?) ways to `do` it?

I got no hits on index/indices when I searched the [`dplyr` help text](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) or [vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). So now I wonder:
Are there other `dplyr` methods to replace parts of a variable using numeric indices which I have overlooked? Specifically, is the creation of an index column in combination with `ifelse` the way to go, or are there more direct `a[i] <- b[i]`-like alternatives?

---

**Edit** following comment from @G.Grothendieck (Thanks!). Added `replace` alternative (a candidate for 'See also' in `?[`).

```
fun_replace <- function(df){
  df %.%
    group_by(grp) %.%
    mutate(
      a = replace(a, id, b[id]))
}
fun_replace(df1)

microbenchmark(fun_do(df3),
               fun_do2(df3),
               fun_mut(df3),
               fun_mut_ifelse(df3),
               fun_replace(df3),
               times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#         fun_do(df3) 685.154605 693.327160 706.055271 712.180410 851.757790    10
#        fun_do2(df3) 291.787455 294.047747 297.753888 299.624730 302.368554    10
#        fun_mut(df3)   5.736640   5.883753   6.206679   6.353222   7.381871    10
# fun_mut_ifelse(df3)  24.321894  26.091049  29.361553  32.649924  52.981525    10
#    fun_replace(df3)   4.616757   4.748665   4.981689   5.279716   5.911503    10
```

`replace` function is fastest, and for sure easier to use than `fun_mut` when there are more than one index.

**Edit 2** `fun_do` and `fun_do2` no longer works in `dplyr 0.2`; `Error: Results are not data frames at positions:`

Comment: Try `mutate(a = replace(a, id, b[id]))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I added your function to the benchmark. It is the fastest so far and indeed cleaner than my 'concatenating' function. Cheers.

Comment: You could slightly modify your `mutate` in `fun_mut_ifelse` to `mutate(a = ifelse(1:n() %in% id, b, a))` so you dont need to create an index first and deselect it later on. I dont know if that has a performance impact, though.

Comment: IMO, it would also be nice to have something like `unfilter` functionality so that you could do in this example: `df3 %.% group_by(grp) %.% filter(1:n() %in% id) %.% mutate(a = b) %.% unfilter()` which might be faster than with `ifelse` b/c only the filtered rows would be operated on (just a hypothesis, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more context about the real problem? I'm interested in understanding the context.

Comment: @hadley, Thank you for your comment. Even if you didn't ping me, I suppose it was for me? I just 'dropped by' my question to check for signs of life. My question originated when I was helping a colleague to prepare some genomics data, calculation withing chromosomes, within scaffolds, between scaffolds. A long chain of data massage with grouping, mutate, summarize, new grouping, mutate...and so on. Everything went really smooth. However, at one point the first value in one column needed to be replaced by the first in another, no "real" conditional replacement as described in the posts...

Comment: @hadley, continued from above: ...I linked to in my question, but I needed a replacement by numeric index. I had some ideas of how to do it in `dplyr`, but given that I needed to deliver the script quickly, I ended up using `ddply` with an anonymous function, similar to the script in the question. Then I started to think that I really must have overlooked something in `dplyr` on how to use a seemingly simple "replace-by-numeric-index-anonymous-function".

Comment: @hadley, My intention was to make my question more general than my specific problem of "how to replace first element". Therefore I described the problem as replacement by a numeric _vector_ of indices. I hope this made things clearer. A spin-off question that appeared when I tried my three potential `dplyr` solutions was that `do` was so much slower than the `mutate` functions. With `dplyr 0.2` the `do` code in the question is now broken, and I haven't had time to rewrite it. Please let me know if I need to clarify my context further. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: @Henrik Hmmm, so the real problem only involved replacing a single value. Thanks.

Comment: @hadley, Yes, that's true, that was my narrow sense problem. The more broad sense problem was a wish to improve my understanding of the use of replacement by numeric index in `dplyr`, be it one or several values. I found the `a[i] <- b[i]` type which I have used in `ddply` straightforward, and hoped to for input for a somewhat canonical `dplyr` equivalent. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a much faster modify-in-place approach:

```
library(data.table)

# select rows we want, then assign b to a for those rows, in place
fun_dt = function(dt) dt[dt[, .I[id], by = grp]$V1, a := b]

# benchmark
df4 = data.frame(grp = rep(1:20000, each = 3),
                 a = rnorm(60000),
                 b = rnorm(60000))
dt4 = as.data.table(df4)

library(microbenchmark)

# using fastest function from OP
microbenchmark(fun_dt(dt4), fun_replace(df4), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#      fun_dt(dt4) 15.62325  17.22828  18.42445  20.83768  21.25371    10
# fun_replace(df4) 99.03505 107.31529 116.74830 188.89134 286.50199    10
```

Comment: @Henrik np - if you're looking for great speeds and great syntax I don't see any reason for not learning to use `data.table`; FYI if/when [FR 2793](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2793&group_id=240&atid=978) gets implemented the syntax for this problem will become much simpler/more natural: `dt[, a[id] := b[id], by = grp]`

Comment: @Henrik my understanding is that `dplyr`'s philosophy is against modifying in place, which puts a lower bound on how fast it can be for these types of operations

Comment: @Henrik I firmly believe that `data.table` syntax inertia is a myth that originated from people who were too used to `plyr` syntax. If you approach it with a clean slate - it's extremely simple - `d[i, j, by = b]` is read as *"take `d`, apply `i`, compute `j` grouped by `b`"*. Once you understand that much, you'll understand 90% of `data.table` syntax.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong - my notion about inertia says more about me than about `data.table` ;)