# IF then do end equivalent in r... EDIT: in dplyr

Tags: r

Imagine a vector `animals <- c("dog", "wolf", "cat"); animals <- as.data.frame(animals)`

I'd like to create a new vector that looks like this: `animals$dogs <- c("dog", "dog", "cat)`

Is there a `dplyr` function that will perform this operation?

Comment: What's the logic behind that? Take the first element twice and then the third?

Comment: if animals = "dog" then dogs = "dogs"; if animals = "wolf" then dogs = "dogs"; if animals = "cat" then dogs = "cat"

Comment: what about `ifelse(animals %in% c("dog","wolf"),"dog","cat")` ?

Comment: `ifelse` is your friend for such problems, as shown by Ben Bolker. It takes vector input as opposed to `if`... `else` constructs. Read `?ifelse`

Comment: sure - that works... wondering if there is a `dplyr` method as I am transitioning a lot of my cleaning/scrubbing data processes to using the library.

Comment: `dplyr` is a package specially created for working with data.frame-like objects, not atomic vectors.

Comment: whoops, @docendodiscimus, I'll edit my question...

Comment: If it was a factor vector, you could change the factor levels for wolf to dog.

Comment: That's another great way @docendodiscimus - however I'm wondering about a dplyr solution - I should probably change my title to reflect that... sorry.

Comment: You should probably specify why it needs to be dplyr.  If there really is no reason other than you think it will provide the fastest/best solution then don't mention it at all - if it is the best people will provide a solution like that.  If you were asking a question about how to do something around the house you wouldn't put some restriction on it before you knew the possible solutions "I need to open a door - please use a chisel in your solution" <- there are plenty of good non-chisel solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
animals <- data.frame(animals=c("dog", "wolf", "cat"))
```

I believe the `dplyr` idiom would be:

```
library("dplyr")
animals %>% mutate(dogs=ifelse(animals %in% c("dog","wolf"),
                                  "dog",
                                  "cat"))
```

You could also use `car::recode()` for this.

```
library("car")
animals %>% mutate(dogs=recode(animals,"c('dog','wolf')='dog'"))
```

Comment: You could also use `replace` instead of `ifelse`. Think I remember seeing a benchmark where that was faster than `ifelse`.

Comment: The reference I was thinking of is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642811/replace-parts-of-a-variable-using-numeric-indices-in-dplyr-do-i-need-to-create).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I can think of is to subset the vector or data.frame and replace the "wolf" entries directly without `ifelse`:

```
animals <- c("dog", "wolf", "cat")
dogs <- animals
dogs[dogs == "wolf"] <- "dog"
```

Or in case of a data.frame:

```
animals <- data.frame(animals=c("dog", "wolf", "cat"))
animals$dog <- animals$animals
animals$dog[animals$dog == "wolf"] <- "dog"
```

The advantage should be that you're only modifying a subset of the data instead of the whole vector. If your data is small, it probably won't make a difference or could even be slower than ifelse, but for a larger vector I believe it would perform better (not benchmarked, though).