# create new variable defined only for a subset of the data using `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this example data:

```
set.seed(1234567)
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = runif(10), var2 = c(runif(5), rep(NA, 5)))
```

And this EXAMPLE vectorized function that, unfortunately, triggers an error whenever one of the arguments is `NA`

```
myfn <- function(x, y){
    sum(x:y)
}
myfn <- Vectorize(myfn)
```

Now, in the middle of a `dplyr` chain I need to create a new variable using `myfn`. This new var (`var3`) is only defined when `var1` and `var2` are not `NA`.

So the most common solution for similar situations is to use `ifelse`. Something like this.

```
mydf %>%
    mutate(var3 = ifelse(
        test = is.na(var2), 
        yes = NA, 
        no = myfn(var1, var2)))
```

But this does not work in my case because `ifelse` anyway actually passes the whole vector `var1` and `var2` to `myfn` and not just the sub-vector when `test` is `FALSE`. And it all breaks because `myfn` breaks whenever receives a `NA`.

So, what is the clever `dplyr` solution for this? (I can think of many solutions for this without using `dplyr`, but I am just interested in a `dplyr`-friendly solution)

It occurred to me that `filter` could help and indeed works with a very readable and `dplyr`y code

```
mydf %>%
    filter(!is.na(var2)) %>%
    mutate(var3 = myfn(var1, var2))

        var1       var2       var3
1 0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
2 0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
3 0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
4 0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
5 0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
```

But then I would have to save this in a temporary object, then create `var3` in the original data all with `NA` and put all back together in the same data ('cause as far as I know the `unfilter` that some have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642811/replace-parts-of-a-variable-using-numeric-indices-in-dplyr-do-i-need-to-create) does not exist, ..., yet).

So just to illustrate the output I want, this code produces it (no using `dplyr` at all):

```
mydf$var3 <- NA
index <- !is.na(mydf$var2)
mydf$var3[index] <- myfn(mydf$var1[index], mydf$var2[index])
mydf

> mydf
         var1       var2       var3
1  0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
2  0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
3  0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
4  0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
5  0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
6  0.48005398         NA         NA
7  0.08837960         NA         NA
8  0.86294587         NA         NA
9  0.49660306         NA         NA
10 0.85350403         NA         NA
```

**EDIT:**

I accepted @krlmlr's solution because it is what I was looking for: clear, easily readable and concise code that effortlessly integrate in a `dplyr` chain. For my example, this solution looks like this.

```
mydf %>%
        rowwise %>%
        mutate(var3 = if(is.na(var2)) NA else myfn(var1, var2))
```

However, as @krlmlr pointed out in his answer, to operate row by row has a cost in terms of performance. It may not be significant for small data sets or single time operations, but for larger data sets or repeating the operation millions of times, it could be considerable. To illustrate, here's a comparison using `microbenchmark` and three solutions (base, dyplr and data.table) applied over a somewhat larger data set (not massive or anything, just 1000 rows instead of 10 in my original example).

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234567)
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = runif(1000), var2 = c(runif(500), rep(NA, 500)))

myfn <- function(x, y){
    sum(x:y)
}
myfn <- Vectorize(myfn)

using_base <- function(){
    mydf$var3 <- NA
    index <- !is.na(mydf$var2)
    mydf$var3[index] <- myfn(mydf$var1[index], mydf$var2[index])
}

using_dplyr <- function(){
    mydf <- mydf %>%
        rowwise %>%
        mutate(var3 = if(is.na(var2)) NA else myfn(var1, var2))
}

using_datatable <- function(){
    setDT(mydf)[!is.na(var2), var3 := myfn(var1, var2)]
}

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
    using_base(), using_dplyr(), using_datatable(), 
    times = 1000)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

And as you can see, the `dplyr` solution using `rowwise` is considerably slower than its `base` and `data.table` rivals.

Comment: Your function is only copying non `NA` values from `var1` into `var3`, is that intended?

Comment: it is an example function. That's not my actual function. It's just an example to provide here a short reproducible code that illustrates the issue

Comment: How about fixing your function so that it doesn't break when it receives NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original function isn't vectorized and cannot cope with certain inputs, there's no performance benefit in vectorizing it using `Vectorize()`. Instead, use `dplyr::rowwise()` to operate row by row:

```
iris %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(x = if (Sepal.Length < 5) 1 else NA) %>%
  ungroup
```

Note that using `if` here is perfectly safe, as the input has length 1.

Comment: thanks, `rowwise` is a good idea. But I have only seen it used with `do`. I'll try and let you know how it goes. ..., meanwhile, I just copy-pasted your code to see the output but it raises this error "Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector", ..., I haven't investigated what is going on there (later I'll do), but if you read this before it'd be nice to hear what may be causing the error

Comment: To avoid the error, use `NA_real_` instead of `NA`.

Comment: @elikesprogramming: I'm using the dev version of dplyr, the error doesn't occur here. Otherwise, `NA_real_` is a safe option.

Comment: yeah, dev version fixed that, ..., thanks, your solution seems to me very `dyplr`-y (and most importantly, clear and concise code) and works great (on dev version of `dyplr`)

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps consider using `data.table`, given that `dplyr` currently does not support [in-place mutation](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/425), which is what you seem to be looking for.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[!is.na(var2), var3 := myfn(var1, var2)]
#        var1       var2       var3
# 1: 0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
# 2: 0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
# 3: 0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
# 4: 0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
# 5: 0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
# 6: 0.48005398         NA         NA
# 7: 0.08837960         NA         NA
# 8: 0.86294587         NA         NA
# 9: 0.49660306         NA         NA
#10: 0.85350403         NA         NA
```

Comment: thanks @mtoto, yeah such partial replacements is a very nice feature of `data.table`. I was just looking for something similar using `dplyr` because even though I am a fan of `data.table` performance, not so much about its syntax (kind of obscure and difficult to grasp, ..., not in this case, though; for this particular case the code is also very clear, but in some cases the code for `data.table`-based solutions is hard to read)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other options you could use in dplyr-pipes:

**a) with a temporary variable**

```
mutate(mydf, temp = !(is.na(var1) | is.na(var2)),
       var3 = replace(NA, temp, myfn(var1[temp], var2[temp])),
       temp = NULL)
#         var1       var2       var3
#1  0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
#2  0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
#3  0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
#4  0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
#5  0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
#6  0.48005398         NA         NA
#7  0.08837960         NA         NA
#8  0.86294587         NA         NA
#9  0.49660306         NA         NA
#10 0.85350403         NA         NA
```

**b) with a wrapper function (without changing the original `myfn`):**

```
myfn2 <- function(x, y) {
  i <- !(is.na(x) | is.na(y))
  res <- rep(NA, length(x))
  res[i] <- myfn(x[i], y[i])
  res
}

mutate(mydf, var3 = myfn2(var1, var2))
#         var1       var2       var3
#1  0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
#2  0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
#3  0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
#4  0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
#5  0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
#6  0.48005398         NA         NA
#7  0.08837960         NA         NA
#8  0.86294587         NA         NA
#9  0.49660306         NA         NA
#10 0.85350403         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run the function on the complete rows and then bind back the rows with `NA` (though this is more roundabout than the `if`... `else` approach):

```
mydf %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  mutate(var3 = myfn(var1, var2)) %>%
  bind_rows(mydf %>% filter(!complete.cases(.)))
```

> ```
>          var1       var2       var3
>         (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
> 1  0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
> 2  0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
> 3  0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
> 4  0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
> 5  0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
> 6  0.48005398         NA         NA
> 7  0.08837960         NA         NA
> 8  0.86294587         NA         NA
> 9  0.49660306         NA         NA
> 10 0.85350403         NA         NA
> ```

Comment: It's also costly, because also the unrelated columns are ripped apart and stuck back together for no reason :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great case to adopt the [pythonic style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) of begging forgiveness rather than asking permission.

You can solve this with `tryCatch` and avoid condition-testing altogether:

```
myfn <- function(x, y){ 
  tryCatch(sum(x:y), error = function(e) NA)
}
```

Then

```
myfn <- Vectorize(myfn)
mydf %>%
    mutate(var3 = myfn(var1, var2))
```

gives the desired result

```
         var1       var2       var3
1  0.56226084 0.62588794 0.56226084
2  0.72649850 0.24145251 0.72649850
3  0.91524985 0.03768974 0.91524985
4  0.02969437 0.51659297 0.02969437
5  0.76750970 0.81845788 0.76750970
6  0.48005398         NA         NA
7  0.08837960         NA         NA
8  0.86294587         NA         NA
9  0.49660306         NA         NA
10 0.85350403         NA         NA
```

**Addendum**

Of course, it's a good idea to only pass NA on the right type of error, which is

```
> tryCatch(sum(NA:NA), error = function(e) print(str(e)))
List of 2
 $ message: chr "NA/NaN argument"
 $ call   : language NA:NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
NULL
```

Comment: thanks @jaimedash nice idea to use `tryCatch`, although I'd do it in the `dplyr` chain rather than in the function (partly because the function is not as simple as this example I posted, and although I could write a wrapper function to try and catch errors, I am not a fan of such wrappers)

Comment: It makes sense to avoid rewriting the function. The idea of putting `tryCatch` directly in the chain as an inline wrapper seems cool, but when I try e.g., `mydf %>%   mutate(var3 = tryCatch(myfn(var1, var2), error = function(e) NA))` then var3 is all NA. How to make it work? (PS  `rowwise` doesn't help either)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think inline `tryCatch` with `rowwise` could work. Without `rowwise` I guess it should not work, because, again, the whole vector is passed to the function and the `tryCatch` will get an error and give you NA back. In any case, the `rowwise` solution works for sure using `do` instead of `mutate` (this last one perhaps only work on dev version of `dplyr`?). Check out the comment of @Psidom in his own answer below, the code he provides there works.

Comment: +1 thanks! yes I see mutate + rowwise is broken in 0.4.3 but fixed in dev (e.g., issue #1643 in hadley/dplyr github repo)